# Converting string back to an array from local storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, variables, local-storage

Im probably miles off but can anyone tell me if this is possible.

```
 function myFunction(){

 var myArray = (localStorage.getItem("storedArray"));
 myArray = jQuery.makeArray( myArray );

 myArray.push(['someone@myemail','15','myUsername']);
 localStorage.setItem("storedArray", JSON.stringify(grabArray));

 localStorage.removeItem("storedArray");

 }
```

Every time this function is ran i'm wanting to get an array from local storage push values to it and then store it back, so like updating it. The idea is that once an event happens in my application, this item will be cleared, to start logging again.

When i've got the item from local storage i've attempted to turn it back into an array but i don't think this is the way to do it as it isn't returning anything. Can anything be done with JSON?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function myFunction() {
            var storedArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("storedArray"));

            if (storedArray === null) {
                storedArray = [];
            }

            var obj = {
                email: "test@email.com",
                age: 15,
                name: "username"
            };

            storedArray.push(obj);
            localStorage.setItem("storedArray", JSON.stringify(storedArray));
        }
```

Setting the updated storedArray to same key in local storage overwrites the old value. Try this code and you'll see the updated array.

Info: Local Storage data is stored as key-value.

Trott was right, you missed to parse the json that you saved.

JSON.stringify converts your json object/array into a string. In order to get back the same data you have to parse it.

Comment: How to handle if duplicate key value pair is pushed to localStorage?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `JSON.stringify()` to convert the object to a JSON string representation, then you can use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert the JSON representation back to the object.

Comment: could you edit the answer at all to show how this works please, i've not been doing js long.